# Windows Batch - How to search muliple variables then create new variables with their name

Tags: variables, search, batch-file

I have a batch file that pulls in all the command line arguments and stores them as variables. I then search for a name in each, then make a new variable of that name but with new content (rem). I have the first search done here but I don't know how to search all the others without repeating the same commands. I tried it by doing that and it didn't work. Anyway if there is an easier way than this please tell.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set var1=noisereduction-01
set var2=sharpener-03
set var3=resize-02
set var4=output-01
set var5=grain-02
set var6=crf-21
set var7=preset-veryfast
set var8=tune-film
set var9=ref-2
set var10=outputdir-g:\output
set var11=mode-3

for /l %%N in (1 1 11) do call :test var%%N
exit /b

:test  variableName
echo !%1!|>nul findstr /rx .*noisereduction.* && set !%1!=rem
echo %1 = !%1!
exit /b
```

Whoops, there is an error above. I want to create a new var with the name of "noisereduction-01" and a value of "rem", not just give var1 a value of rem. I thought the set !%1!=rem would do it but it is not.

Answer (score 4):

Let's see this problem. When

```
set var1=noisereduction-01
```

... and

```
for /l %%N in (1 1 11) do call :test var%%N
```

... then the first call to test is with "var1" parameter. This mean that into test:

```
set !%1!=rem  IS  set !var1!=rem  IS  set noisereduction-01=rem
```

... that correctly do what you want.

HOWEVER:

```
echo %1 = !%1!  IS  echo var1 = !var1!  IS  echo var1 = noisereduction-01
```

If you want to show the value of noisereduction-01 variable, then you must perform an additional expansion step:

```
for %%v in (!%1!) do echo param: %1, variable: !%1!, value: !%%v!
```

Comment: Ok, you are correct. So how do I do this for all the variables in my list, a "for" command??

Comment: @tyee - if you need to control something in Batch, mostly you need a `for` loop.

Comment: @tyee: You already have the `for /l %%N in (1 1 11) do call :test var%%N` loop to review all the _variables_ in your list, just add the additional expansion inside `:test` subroutine. I am missing something?